How can I Enabling JDBC Driver Uploads on jasper server version 9?
I want to add oracle ojdbc6 driver to jasper server version 9
when I go to New data source page I cannot find Select driver to install the driver ,
I checked the following link they write to enable JDBC driver upload login in
as superuser I logged in as jasperadmin is this user super user ?
Select Manage > Server Settings and choose General from the left-hand panel. 

https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server/tibco-jasperreports-server-administration-guide/v900/jasperreports-server-admin-guide-_-datasources-_-managing_jdbc_drivers/#EnableJDBCdriverUpload

but in manage there is no choice server settings ?
only under manage there is Organizations , users , roles and admin console .
how can I solve this issue please and add the driver also is there any other super user instead of jasper admin ?

I found the following in jasper community website
Jasper Reports Server no longer includes JDBC drivers for the following commercial databases:
DB2
Oracle
SQL Server
I uninstalled version 9 and installed version 7.8 and issue solved and can Select Driver
